# Python. Ищу библиотеку для распознавания речи

Tags: python, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек

Мне нужно любое распознавание речи из аудио файла (для бота в вк), главное что бы был бесплатным есть ли такие? Неважно оффлайн или онлайн.

Comment: Библиотека это вряд ли. Попробуй вклиниться в процессы распознавания аудио Яндекс Алисой или каким-нибудь Гугл переводчиком

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[speech_recognition](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#readme)

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

path = 'speech.wav'

with sr.AudioFile(path) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

    print(r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
```

Comment: Она польностью беслпатная?

Comment: да, https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#requirements

Comment: подскажите: так пишу и выводит:ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format

Comment: Вы ошибку переведите и сразу станет понятно, что нужно у Гугла спрашивать